# Paragraph Spacing & Aligning to Baseline - incompatible?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography, page-layout, book, paragraph-styles

I am working on a 200 page book of letters and would like to use paragraph spacing instead of paragraph indents. The space between paragraph is too large when the baseline grid is set to leading, but if the baseline grid is set to half the leading the lines of text on opposite and flip-side pages are then misaligned by half a line. I have researched but can't seem to find an answer.
**Is there a way to both use half-leading paragraph spacing and align facing text to the same baseline?** Thank you!

Comment: No theres no way of ensuring that (x+0.5)%1.0==x

Comment: That is not geometrically possible. Try making a sketch of it. Not possible. You have to choose between the two. See [my answer to another question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/137376/84899). It's not the same question, but I visualize the problem with using paragraph spacing less than the leading.

Comment: Apart from the fact that there’s no way to make half a line align with a whole line, as a general rule, **you shouldn’t use paragraph spacing for books** at all. It looks amateurish, for the simple reason that that’s now how books are set. Kind of a self-fulfilling prophecy or a circular argument, but that’s how it is: convention breeds convention.